# How to I convert the following ellipse into its general form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How to I convert the following ellipse into its general form?
>   $$4x^2+9y^2-18y=27$$

By general form I mean: 
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

Comment: Complete the square on the terms with $y$.

Answer (score 2):

Complete the square on the terms with a $y$:

$$4x^2+9y^2-18y=27$$

$$4x^2+9(y^2-2y +1 - 1)=27$$

$$4x^2+9(y-1)^2 - 9=27$$

$$\frac{x^2}{3^2}+\frac{(y-1)^2}{2^2} =1$$